# How can I write $6$ as products of irreducibles in the Gaussian Integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Moreover, how can I prove that $2+i$ and $1+i$ are irreducibles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you start by factoring it in $\mathbb{Z}$, and then check if those divisors can be further reduced?

For your second question, recall that for any complex numbers $a$ and $b$, $\|ab\|^2=\|a\|^2\|b\|^2$. So since $\|2+i\|^2 = 5$ is prime, if $2+i=ab$ then... can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, the (field-theoretic) norm, $z\mapsto z\overline z$ in this case, is the key to all questions of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

i have noticed that $6=2*3 $. now $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ and 3 must be irreducible because cannot be written as product of two squares. but again I have tried to prove that 1+i is irreducible and I end up in a vicious circle, ie that it can be written as a product of a unit times either $(+1+i),(1-i) , (-1-i),(i-1)$.

Comment: Can it be written as the product of two *non-units*, though? (See my answer for a hint on how to prove the answer).

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302502/show-if-these-gaussian-integers-are-irreducible-or-not/302537#302537