# Factor ring of Gaussian integers is a field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, gaussian-integers

I want to show that $E=\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle2-i\rangle$ is a field.

To do this, I note that $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Moreover, a maximal ideal is a prime ideal in a commutative ring with unity. We have exactly this in the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Hence, it suffices to show that $\langle2-i\rangle$ is prime or maximal. I am not sure which is easier to show and in either case how to do so. Any suggestions where to begin?

Comment: There's a useful magnitude function $f: \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(x+yi) = x^2+y^2$, with the property that $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$. If $2-i = ab$, then $f(2-i) = 5 = f(a)f(b)$...

Comment: $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a PID, so prime and maximal is the same. We know a lot on maximal and prime ideals then, see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292724/describe-the-maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-gaussian-integers-bbb-zi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Also see again [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers?noredirect=1&lq=1) which shows that $\Bbb Z[i]/(2-i)\cong \Bbb F_5$ is a field. Hence $(2-i)$ is maximal (and prime).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quotient ring of Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers)

Comment: @DietrichBurde To confirm, would I be correct here in saying $E$ is a field because $\langle2-i\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as $2-i$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct - see also the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302502/show-if-these-gaussian-integers-are-irreducible-or-not).